# what is the simplest way to log information or debugging a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-services

I need to debug a Windows Service, from Visual Studio I cannot run the Service so I am using Installutil.exe.

So after every build I use Installutil.exe but I cannot go step by step in my code.

Do you know any simple way to:

- Using VS debugger to check the code?
- Or logging some message in Events so I can trace what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: I typically use some AOP tool, like PostSharp to insert `Trace.WriteLine` calls (you can do that yourself too). When I need to troubleshoot, I setup a [Trace Listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a logger like [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to write to a file, but if you want to debug there's a way to [attach the debugger to a running process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> So after every build I use Installutil.exe but I cannot go step by
>   step in my code.

If you want to debug the service in Visual studio then you can do the following.

In `Program.cs` file define:

```
private static void RunService()
{
    var service = new YourService();
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(service);
}

//for debug only
private static void RunNoService()
{
    using (var service = new YourService())
    {
        service.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

In `Main` method

```
static void Main()
{
    if (Environment.UserInteractive) //This is IMPORTANT
        RunNoService();
    else
        RunService();
}
```

In your service Define a `Start` method which would have the functionality from `OnStart`, Modify your `OnStart` method as:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Start();
}
```

`Environment.UserInteractive` would check if the service is being run from Visual Studio and let you debug it.

**For Logging:**

Always log your activity in your service. That will help you debugging your service once it is in production. You can use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or you can create your own custom class for logging. Even logging to a simple Text file would be better than not having anything. But you must keep log, otherwise it could become really frustrating if something goes wrong in the production.

Answer (score 1):

To debug a service in Visual Studio I'm using this code in the Service project:

In **Program.cs**:

```
    static class Program
    {
#if DEBUG
        static AutoResetEvent sare = new AutoResetEvent(false);
#endif

        static void Main()
        {
#if (!DEBUG)           
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Service() };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#else
            Service service = new Service();
            service.DebugServiceStopped += new Action(SetAutoResetEvent);

            service.DebugStart();

            sare.WaitOne();
#endif
        }

#if DEBUG
        private static void SetAutoResetEvent()
        {
            sare.Set();
        }
#endif        
    }
```

In **Service.cs** (file of the actual `Service` class) you need to add these code parts:

```
#if DEBUG
        public event Action DebugServiceStopped;
        public void DebugStart()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }
#endif

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
#if DEBUG
            DebugServiceStopped();
#endif
        }
```

If you select `Debug` as configuration in Visual Studio you will be able to debug the Service just as a normal application, otherwise the project will be compiled as a real Service.

**Logging:**
On Windows there is the **Windows Event Log** that is used to store information, warnings and errors of applications. From a Service the event log can be written into with:

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("your log message", EventLogEntryType.Information); // or EventLogEntryType.Error,... depending on the entry type
```